# How to fix toArray is not undefined in Jest

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jestjs

I'm create a unit test with Jest and run the tests I get a error with the test: "TypeError: db.find(...).toArray is not a function". if someone can help me I'll be grateful.

greetings :)

```
'use strict';
const DB = require('../../../../app/databases/mongo');
jest.mock('../../../../app/databases/mongo');

const noteController = require('../../../../app/controllers/note');

function functionMock(returnValue) {
    const find = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(returnValue));
    return jest.fn(() => ({
        find: () => ({ find })
    }));
}

describe('noteController', () => {

    beforeAll(() => {
        DB.getDb.mockImplementation(functionMock(null));
    });

    describe('note controller', () => {
        describe('find', () => {
            it('note list', async done => {
                const ctx = jest.fn();              
                await noteController.find(ctx)
                .then(result => {
                    expect(result).toBeDefined();
                });
                done();
            })
        })
    })

});
```

I expect the output with data in the promise resolve but i get: "TypeError: db.find(...).toArray is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't show us where `db` comes from, but my guess is that `db.find(...)` does not return a result set.

Change your code to be:

```
var dbResult = db.find(...)
expect(dbResult.toArray).toBeDefined
```

That will allow you to assert that you have an object with the `toArray` method defined.

There's probably a better way to assert that, but you didn't include enough code to figure it out so I'm guessing.

Comment: The find method in the controller is:

https://pastebin.com/QVGSp2YP

exports.find = async ctx => {
db = MongoClient.getDb();
  await db.find({}, { '_id': 0 }).toArray()
    .then((result) => {
        let msj = dto.transform(result, 'array');
        return ctx.res.ok({ data: msj });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};